# How to parse particular value from each cell in a database?

Tags: sql, excel, swift, parsing, oracle11g

I am trying to parse particular SWIFT tag from each cell, For example I want to parse the tags ":32BUSD292317" and ":33B:GBP6299876,00", from a message like this:

```
:15A:
:20:2
:22A:NEWT
:94A:AFWD
:17O:Y
:17N:Y
:83J:/ACCT/12345
:32B:USD9292317,10
:33B:GBP6299876,00
:15C:
:29A:/NAME/Richard Jones/PHON/212-1234567
```

so far I have this SQL, but I do not know how to parse the particular line into its own column. Can some one please help me with this portion? I can also export the messages into a excel spread sheet but do not know how to break into text-column for messages of not the same size.So if its easier in excel I am open to all suggestions.

```
select * from t.SWIFTMessage
instr(swift_message,"32B:USD")>0
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest exploring `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a regex something like `'^:32B:USD.*$'`, but you'll have to experiment to get the right regex.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007670

Comment: Going off of that, this is a graphic way to test it: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention text-column so assuming each row ends up in Excel in a separate cell, one solution might be to apply Text to Columns with `:` as the delimiter. The fact that each line is a different length makes no difference. If applied to just the two rows in which you are interested (say Rows8 and 9 from ColumnA) the result would be `32B` in B8, `33B` in B9, `USD9292317,10` in C8 and `GBP6299876,00` in C9. The fact that they are moved out of ColumnA may be convenient for then deleting the whole of that column.